# How to get rid of default bar under tab

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been trying to customize the tab bar of my app. I've got nearly everything working except for the part that the default blue thin line shows up above my custom drawable for the tabs.
I will attach a screenshot and the xml styles.

[image: TabBar]

1. styles.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <!-- Custom ActionBar -->
           <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
           <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/gray</item>

           <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TabStyle</item>
           <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TabText</item>
       </style>

       <!-- Custom ActionBar -->
       <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
           <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
           <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/white</item>
       </style>

       <style name="MyActionBar.TitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
           <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary</item>
       </style>

       <style name="MyActionBar.TabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
           <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_myactionbar</item>
       </style>

       <style name="MyActionBar.TabText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
           <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray</item>
       </style>

   </resources>
   ```
2. drawable/tab_indicator_myactionbar.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <!-- Non focused -->
       <item
           android:state_focused="false"
           android:state_selected="false"
           android:state_pressed="false"
           android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

       <item
           android:state_focused="false"
           android:state_selected="true"
           android:state_pressed="false"
           android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_myactionbar" />

      <!-- Focused -->
      <item
          android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focused_unselected_myactionbar" />

      <item
          android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focused_selected_myactionbar" />

      <!-- Pressed -->
      <!--    Non focused -->
      <item
          android:state_focused="false"
          android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_myactionbar" />

      <item
          android:state_focused="false"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_myactionbar" />

      <!--    Focused -->
      <item
          android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_myactionbar" />

      <item
          android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_myactionbar" />

   </selector>
   ```

Comment: it may help you http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: I did try that, used the same code but they still show up. Can't find anything in the generated code that points at changing / removing those lines either.